# C# Excel Interop: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC while using Range.set_Value

Tags: c#, export-to-excel, excel-interop

I am using Office Interop libraries in a C# WinForms application to write around 25000 rows and 110 columns data to Excel 2016. The max value length for any element is 420 characters.

I am using a 2 dimensional object array to read values from a DataTable, and I am passing this array to `Range.set_Value` method.

The application is working fine for other DataTables, but for a particular data, I am getting error:

> C# Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

while using `Range.set_Value`. I am unable to figure out which of the 25000 rows and 110 columns is causing the error.

I can of course start breaking the data into small chunks until I identify which exact row and column is causing the issue, but is there a better way to debug the issue?

The data may have all kinds of special characters (the data is generated by a third party app).

**EDIT 1:**

I read that you can't add a cell with more than 8192 chars, if it is Excel 2007. But my data contains max 425 characters in any cell, and my Excel version is 2016.

Comment: you looked for inner exceptions?

Comment: The InnerException is null

Comment: COM calls fail, you have to have a plan for it.  You should also look at implementing a IMessageFilter so that you can tell COM to retry.  Even with the filter however you'll want to implement some type of retry strategy.

Comment: The COM call is failing only with a particular data containing about 25000 rows and it's not working after multiple retry attempts. The same code is working for all other datasets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the issue with the data after some trial and error.

A few elements in the 2-dimensional array were starting with "=" character, which is treated as the start of a formula in Excel. Since the element value was not a valid formula, so Excel was throwing Exception.

I prepended those text values with a ' symbol, and everything worked fine.

Hope this helps somebody.